# How to get integer input with assembly

Tags: assembly

Iam learning assembly and I found out how to get user input with

```
mov al, 3    ; system call number (sys_read)
xor bl, bl   ; file descriptor 0 (stdin)
mov rcx, buf ; buffer to store input
mov dl, 4    ; Lenght of buffer
int 0x80     ; interrupt
```

but that actually gets a string right? 
my question is how do i get a integer value...
so if i type 100 how do i get the value 64h so i can add, subtract etc
instead of a  string with each byte being the ascii representation of the number
and then how do i output a value like 64h to the screen so that it shows 100?
i dont need code just some guidance

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like x86. Is this so?

Comment: Lets hope the upper parts of rax, rbx and rdx are 0...

Comment: The other way around: integer to string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117422/more-efficient-way-to-output-an-integer-in-pure-assembly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have the ASCII representation, you can just build up the result digit by digit, using the fact that the numerals are encoded in order. In pseudo-code, reading from left to right (i.e. starting with the most significant digit):

- initialize `result` to 0
- for each digit `c`, `result *= 10; result += (c - '0');`
- `result` holds the numeric value of the string

Comment: +1 The same method applies for other bases (though the `c - '0'` part gets more complicated for bases > 10)

Answer (score 1):

Look at binary coded decimals BCD. It can do this a little more efficiently