# How to print a number in assembly NASM?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

Suppose that I have an integer number in a register, how can I print it? Can you show a simple example code?

I already know how to print a string such as "hello, world".

I'm developing on Linux.

Comment: Please specify the OS where the program will run.

Comment: Related: [convert an integer to an ASCII decimal string in a buffer on the stack and print it with Linux `write` system call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894/224132), not using `printf` or any other functions.  With comments and explanation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're already on Linux, there's no need to do the conversion yourself. Just use [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) instead:

```
;
; assemble and link with:
; nasm -f elf printf-test.asm && gcc -m32 -o printf-test printf-test.o
;
section .text
global main
extern printf

main:

  mov eax, 0xDEADBEEF
  push eax
  push message
  call printf
  add esp, 8
  ret

message db "Register = %08X", 10, 0
```

Note that `printf` uses the [cdecl calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) so we need to restore the stack pointer afterwards, i.e. add 4 bytes per parameter passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the what I was looking for. Do you know if it works also on Mac os X?

Comment: How to compile it on 64-bit?

Comment: 2021 update: you may need `gcc -m32 -no-pie`, or at least it's a good idea if you're going to do `call printf` instead of `call printf@plt`, and also to use absolute addresses as immediates, not position-independent.  In practice for 32-bit code you can usually get away with it.

Answer (score 17):

You have to convert it in a string; if you're talking about hex numbers it's pretty easy. Any number can be represented this way:

```
0xa31f = 0xf * 16^0 + 0x1 * 16^1 + 3 * 16^2 + 0xa * 16^3
```

So when you have this number you have to split it like I've shown then convert every "section" to its ASCII equivalent.
Getting the four parts is easily done with some bit magic, in particular with a right shift to move the part we're interested in in the first four bits then AND the result with 0xf to isolate it from the rest. Here's what I mean (soppose we want to take the 3):

```
0xa31f -> shift right by 8 = 0x00a3 -> AND with 0xf = 0x0003
```

Now that we have a single number we have to convert it into its ASCII value. If the number is smaller or equal than 9 we can just add 0's ASCII value (0x30), if it's greater than 9 we have to use a's ASCII value (0x61).
Here it is, now we just have to code it:

```
    mov si, ???         ; si points to the target buffer
    mov ax, 0a31fh      ; ax contains the number we want to convert
    mov bx, ax          ; store a copy in bx
    xor dx, dx          ; dx will contain the result
    mov cx, 3           ; cx's our counter

convert_loop:
    mov ax, bx          ; load the number into ax
    and ax, 0fh         ; we want the first 4 bits
    cmp ax, 9h          ; check what we should add
    ja  greater_than_9
    add ax, 30h         ; 0x30 ('0')
    jmp converted

greater_than_9:
    add ax, 61h         ; or 0x61 ('a')

converted:
    xchg    al, ah      ; put a null terminator after it
    mov [si], ax        ; (will be overwritten unless this
    inc si              ; is the last one)

    shr bx, 4           ; get the next part
    dec cx              ; one less to do
    jnz convert_loop

    sub di, 4           ; di still points to the target buffer
```

**PS:** I know this is 16 bit code but I still use the old TASM :P

**PPS:** this is Intel syntax, converting to AT&T syntax isn't difficult though, look [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180331051340/http://www.imada.sdu.dk:80/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm).

Comment: You don't *need* AT&T syntax to run this on linux.

Comment: @AndreiBârsan: You're right, fixed that.. It's such an old answer :)

Comment: IMHO, this answer is better since you don't need the C runtime (which a call to `printf(...)` requires.

Comment: @AndreiBârsan yes, and it's kind of pointless using the C runtime in assembly

Comment: 32-bit code: [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756).  32-bit / 64-bit conversion to decimal: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) with 64-bit Linux `syscall` to write to stdout.

Answer (score 14):

**Linux x86-64 with `printf`**

main.asm

```
default rel            ; make [rel format] the default, you always want this.
extern printf, exit    ; NASM requires declarations of external symbols, unlike GAS
section .rodata
    format db "%#x", 10, 0   ; C 0-terminated string: "%#x\n" 
section .text
global main
main:
    sub   rsp, 8             ; re-align the stack to 16 before calling another function

    ; Call printf.
    mov   esi, 0x12345678    ; "%x" takes a 32-bit unsigned int
    lea   rdi, [rel format]
    xor   eax, eax           ; AL=0  no FP args in XMM regs
    call  printf

    ; Return from main.
    xor   eax, eax
    add   rsp, 8
    ret
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-assembly-cheat/blob/54619639a67c1f6b2cf39662b6698ba006d97d11/x86-64/linux/c-from-assembly/printf.asm).

Then:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o main.o main.asm
gcc -no-pie -o main.out main.o
./main.out
```

Output:

```
0x12345678
```

Notes:

- `sub rsp, 8`: [How to write assembly language hello world program for 64 bit Mac OS X using printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691792/how-to-write-assembly-language-hello-world-program-for-64-bit-mac-os-x-using-pri)
- `xor eax, eax`: [Why is %eax zeroed before a call to printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212665/why-is-eax-zeroed-before-a-call-to-printf)
- `-no-pie`: plain `call printf` doesn't work in a PIE executable (`-pie`), the linker only automatically generates a PLT stub for old-style executables.  Your options are:

  - `call printf wrt ..plt` to call through the PLT like traditional `call printf`
  - `call [rel printf wrt ..got]` to not use a PLT at all, like `gcc -fno-plt`.

  Like GAS syntax `call *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)`.

  Either of these are fine in a non-PIE executable as well, and don't cause any inefficiency unless you're statically linking libc. In which case `call printf` can resolve to a `call rel32` directly to libc, because the offset from your code to the libc function would be known at static linking time.

  See also: [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code)

If you want hex without the C library: [Printing Hexadecimal Digits with Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853730/printing-hexadecimal-digits-with-assembly/32756303#32756303)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.10, NASM 2.13.03.

Comment: Please don't recommend `mov` for putting static addresses in registers in 64-bit mode.  Use RIP-relative LEA, unless you're optimizing for position-dependent code where you can use `mov r32, imm32`.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes thanks for the edit. Yes, I think I didn't know what PIE was at the time + many other details :-) If you feel like making it work with `-pie` as well, that would be cool ;-) I'm lazy to research that now.

Comment: I already included `call printf wrt ..plt`  in my first edit.  I put it back in in a more appropriate place now that you made a bullet point for it.  I had to look up the NASM equivalent of GAS `call *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)` , for no-plt style code that does early binding of dynamic symbols instead of lazy linking via the PLT.  (But with the upside of just indirect call instead of call + `jmp` for lazy dynamic linking with a PLT.)

Comment: @PeterCordes ah OK, I thought that was just a pseudo notation, what a weird syntax!

Comment: Agreed.  `.plt` is the section name, and I guess there's an extra `.` in there maybe to go with the with-respect-to abbreviation?

Comment: [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](//stackoverflow.com/q/52126328) has a bit more detail about `call [rel printf wrt ..got]` and `call printf wrt ..plt`.  I just updated it to work for NASM as well as YASM.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the architecture/environment you are using.

For instance, if I want to display a number on linux, the ASM code will be different from the one I would use on windows.

Edit:

You can refer to [THIS](http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1042.0) for an example of conversion.

Comment: A Linux example would be fine.

Comment: @AR89 it's a bad job.. You have to convert the number to ASCII first. Take a look at the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to assembly, and this obviously is not the best solution,
but it's working. The main function is _iprint, it first checks whether the
number in eax is negative, and prints a minus sign if so, than it proceeds
by printing the individual numbers by calling the function _dprint for
every digit. The idea is the following, if we have 512 than it is equal to: 512 = (5 * 10 + 1) * 10 + 2 = Q * 10 + R, so we can found the last digit of a number by dividing it by 10, and
getting the reminder R, but if we do it in a loop than digits will be in a
reverse order, so we use the stack for pushing them, and after that when
writing them to stdout they are popped out in right order.

```
; Build        : nasm -f elf -o baz.o baz.asm
;                ld -m elf_i386 -o baz baz.o
section .bss
c: resb 1 ; character buffer
section .data
section .text
; writes an ascii character from eax to stdout
_cprint:
    pushad        ; push registers
    mov [c], eax  ; store ascii value at c
    mov eax, 0x04 ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1    ; stdout
    mov ecx, c    ; copy c to ecx
    mov edx, 1    ; one character
    int 0x80      ; syscall
    popad         ; pop registers
    ret           ; bye
; writes a digit stored in eax to stdout 
_dprint:
    pushad        ; push registers
    add eax, '0'  ; get digit's ascii code
    mov [c], eax  ; store it at c
    mov eax, 0x04 ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1    ; stdout
    mov ecx, c    ; pass the address of c to ecx
    mov edx, 1    ; one character
    int 0x80      ; syscall
    popad         ; pop registers
    ret           ; bye
; now lets try to write a function which will write an integer
; number stored in eax in decimal at stdout
_iprint:
    pushad       ; push registers
    cmp eax, 0   ; check if eax is negative
    jge Pos      ; if not proceed in the usual manner
    push eax     ; store eax
    mov eax, '-' ; print minus sign
    call _cprint ; call character printing function 
    pop eax      ; restore eax
    neg eax      ; make eax positive
Pos:
    mov ebx, 10 ; base
    mov ecx, 1  ; number of digits counter
Cycle1:
    mov edx, 0  ; set edx to zero before dividing otherwise the
    ; program gives an error: SIGFPE arithmetic exception
    div ebx     ; divide eax with ebx now eax holds the
    ; quotent and edx the reminder
    push edx    ; digits we have to write are in reverse order
    cmp eax, 0  ; exit loop condition
    jz EndLoop1 ; we are done
    inc ecx     ; increment number of digits counter
    jmp Cycle1  ; loop back
EndLoop1:
; write the integer digits by poping them out from the stack
Cycle2:
    pop eax      ; pop up the digits we have stored
    call _dprint ; and print them to stdout
    dec ecx      ; decrement number of digits counter
    jz EndLoop2  ; if it's zero we are done
    jmp Cycle2   ; loop back
EndLoop2:   
    popad ; pop registers
    ret   ; bye
global _start
_start:
    nop           ; gdb break point
    mov eax, -345 ;
    call _iprint  ; 
    mov eax, 0x01 ; sys_exit
    mov ebx, 0    ; error code
    int 0x80      ; край
```

Comment: You can `add '0'` and store your digits in a buffer as you produce them.  Use `dec` do move the pointer downwards.  When you're done, you have a pointer to the last digit you stored, so you can pass that to `sys_write()` (along with the digit count).  This is much more efficient than making a separate system call for every byte, and doesn't really take more code.  It's easy to allocate a buffer long enough to hold the longest possible string of digits, and start at the end, because you know how many decimal digits 2^32 has.

Comment: related: I wrote an integer->string loop as part of this [extended-precision Fibonacci code-golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133618/extreme-fibonacci/135618#135618).  See the `.toascii_digit:` loop.  Of course, that's optimized for size, so it uses a slow `div` [instead of a multiply trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi).

Comment: Thank you this is definitely preferable than calling sys_write for every digit:)

Comment: I posted my int->string + `sys_write` code as a [stand-alone function on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894/224132), with comments.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't say about number representation I wrote the following code for unsigned number with any base(of course not too big), so you could use it:

```asm
BITS 32
global _start

section .text
_start:

mov eax, 762002099 ; unsigned number to print
mov ebx, 36        ; base to represent the number, do not set it too big
call print

;exit
mov eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
int 0x80

print:
mov ecx, esp
sub esp, 36   ; reserve space for the number string, for base-2 it takes 33 bytes with new line, aligned by 4 bytes it takes 36 bytes.

mov edi, 1
dec ecx
mov [ecx], byte 10

print_loop:

xor edx, edx
div ebx
cmp dl, 9     ; if reminder>9 go to use_letter
jg use_letter

add dl, '0'
jmp after_use_letter

use_letter:
add dl, 'W'   ; letters from 'a' to ... in ascii code

after_use_letter:
dec ecx
inc edi
mov [ecx],dl
test eax, eax
jnz print_loop

; system call to print, ecx is a pointer on the string
mov eax, 4    ; system call number (sys_write)
mov ebx, 1    ; file descriptor (stdout)
mov edx, edi  ; length of the string
int 0x80

add esp, 36   ; release space for the number string

ret
```

It's not optimised for numbers with base of power of two and doesn't use `printf` from `libc`.

The function `print` outputs the number with a new line. The number string is formed on stack. Compile by nasm.

Output:

```
clockz
```

https://github.com/tigertv/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/8194141-how-to-print-a-number-in-assembly-nasm

Comment: You're using space below ESP.  That's only safe in cases like this where you know there are no signal handlers installed, and shouldn't be used in functions that could be called in other contexts.  32-bit Linux doesn't guarantee a red-zone.  Also, use `xor edx,edx` / `div` or `cdq` / `idiv` so the zero or sign-extension of the dividend matches the signedness of the division.  In this case you want `xor`/`div` so you always have a positive remainder.  If you want to treat your input as signed, you'll want to test/js and print the unsigned absolute value (with a leading `-` if needed).

Comment: @PeterCordes, Hi, Peter! You're right about safety. It's a partial solution and I didn't think about signed numbers.

Comment: You should still change `idiv` to `div` so it works for the full range of unsigned numbers.  Hmm, actually this might be safe anyway, because 2^32-1 / 10 doesn't overflow EAX.  zero-extending into edx:eax gives you a signed non-negative dividend from 0..2^32-1.

Comment: @PeterCordes, The `idiv` has been replaced. Also I added base for the number. What do you think about it? And else I reserved a buffer on stack for number string with size 32.

Comment: `add esp, 32` should be `sub` to reserve space.  You're stepping on the caller's stack space.  `mov byte [ecx], 10` would be more efficient than setting a register first.  Or even `push 10` / `mov ecx, esp` / `sub esp, 32`.  (For your current version, a large number with base=2 will use 32 digits, but you use up one of your 32 with a newline.)

Comment: Sure, I'm wrong. :) It didn't even break stack in the context. Fixed.