# How to write assembly language hello world program for 64 bit Mac OS X using printf?

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit, printf, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to learn writing assembly language for 64 bit Mac OS. I have no problem with 32 bit Mac OS and both 32 bit and 64 bit Linux.

However, Mac OS 64 bit is different and I couldn't figure out. Therefore I am here to ask for help.

I have not problem using system call to print. However, I would like to learn how to call C functions using 64 bit assembly language of Mac OS.

Please look at the following code

```
.data
_hello:
    .asciz "Hello, world\n"


.text
.globl _main
_main:
    movq $0, %rax
    movq _hello(%rip), %rdi
    call _printf
```

I use 
$ gcc -arch x86_64 hello.s

to assemble and link.

It generates binary code. However, I got a segmentation fault when running it.

I tried adding "subq $8, %rsp" before calling _printf, still the same result as before.

What did I do wrong?

By the way, is that any way to debug this code on Mac? I tried adding -ggdb or -gstab or -gDWARF, and 
$gdb ./a.out, and can't see the code and set break points.

Comment: good article on x86_64 calling conventions: http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2014/04/18/lets-write-some-x86-64/

Comment: eax for vararg count: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212665 , alignment problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324333 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000351 , generic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857273

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't say exactly what the problem you're seeing is, but I'm guessing that you're crashing at the point of the call to `printf`.  This is because OS X (both 32- and 64-bit) requires that the stack pointer have 16-byte alignment at the point of any external function call.

The stack pointer was 16-byte aligned when `_main` was called; that call pushed an eight-byte return address onto the stack, so the stack is not 16-byte aligned at the point of the call to `_printf`.  Subtract eight from `%rsp` before making the call in order to properly align it.

---

So I went ahead and debugged this for you (no magic involved, just use gdb, `break main`, `display/5i $pc`, `stepi`, etc).  The other problem you're having is here:

```
movq _hello(%rip), %rdi
```

This loads the first eight bytes of your string into `%rdi`, which isn't what you want at all (in particular, the first eight bytes of your string are exceedingly unlikely to constitute a valid pointer to a format string, which results in a crash in `printf`).  Instead, you want to load the *address* of the string.  A debugged version of your program is:

```
.cstring
_hello: .asciz "Hello, world\n"

.text
.globl _main
_main:
    sub  $8, %rsp           // align rsp to 16B boundary
    mov  $0, %rax
    lea  _hello(%rip), %rdi // load address of format string
    call _printf            // call printf
    add  $8, %rsp           // restore rsp
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I am aware of the 16 byte stack alignment issue. I added subq $8, %rsp and still get segmentation fault... I am suspecting movq _hello(%rip), %rdi, I am not sure this is right. On Linux I can just use movq _hello, %rdi, but mac will complain that absolute address is not supported.

Comment: Thank again, Stephen! It works! What a magic! I actually tried using leaq. However, I didn't realize even not pushing any parameter on the stack, the stack still has to be aligned by 16 bytes. What a confusing situation!

Comment: What is %rdi in here?

Comment: @KorayTugay: It's not obvious what you're asking; `%rdi` is a register name, specifically the name of the register that contains the first integer/pointer argument (in this case a pointer) of a function call under the OS X x86_64 calling conventions.