# Linux X86-64 assembly and printf

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, binary-data

I am reading some linux assembly manuals and found idea about using  printf() function. I need it to output register values for debugging reasons in binary form to terminal, but now I am tried simply to test that function with text.

I am stuck, because of segfault when I am using pushq instead of pushl. How can I change this program to output strings and binary form of registers?

```
.data
input_prompt:
    .string "Hello, world!"

printf_format:
    .string "%5d "

printf_newline:
    .string "\n"

size:
    .long 0

.text
.globl main
main:
    pushq $input_prompt
    call  printf

    movl  $0, %eax
    ret
```

It was compiled by GCC as:

```
gcc tmp.S -o tmp
```

Comment: A more detailed working example: [Calling printf in x86\_64 using GNU assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38335212)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linux (and Windows) [x86-64 calling convention](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) has the first few arguments *not* on the stack, but in registers instead

See http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf (page 20)

Specifically:

> 1. If the class is MEMORY, pass the argument on the stack.
> 2. If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9 is used.
> 3. If the class is SSE, the next available vector register is used, the registers are taken in the order from %xmm0 to %xmm7.
> 4. If the class is SSEUP, the eightbyte is passed in the next available eightbyte chunk of the last used vector register.
> 5. If the class is X87, X87UP or COMPLEX_X87, it is passed in memory.

The `INTEGER` class is anything that will fit in a general purpose register, so that's what you would use for string pointers as well.

Comment: The [Windows x64 calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy) does also pass some arguments in registers, but is not the same as the Linux calling convention (see the ["Parameter Passing"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx) section in particular).

Comment: And you must pass `eax = 1` to set the number of varargs, and align the stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324333/does-printf-require-additional-stack-space-on-the-x86-64 || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000351/x86-64-linux-assembly-why-printf-with-float-format-string-work-only-with-rsp

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 : _EAX_ would be set to total number of vector registers used. If no vector registers are used (which is probably a more normal case) _EAX_ would be zero. So the value in _EAX_ depends on what you are passing as arguments.