# (x86_64 linux assembly) Why printf with float format string work only with rsp % 0x10 = 0

Tags: linux, assembly, printf, x86-64, calling-convention

I have a problem with write a call of printf on x86_64 linux assembler. If i try print a double value when `rsp % 0x10 != 0`, printf a fall down with segfault.

Look to my code (nasm syntax):

```
[bits 64]
global _start
extern printf
extern pow

section .data
    printf_format db '%lf', 10, 0
section .text
    _start:
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, MEM_VAL

    mov rax, 0x4000000000000000
    mov qword [rsp], rax

    movsd xmm0, qword [rsp]
    mov rdi, printf_format
    mov rax, 1
    call printf

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

If `MEM_VAL = 0x10, 0x20, ... , 0x100, ...` all is good. Code work. But with another value code is down with segfault. Why?

I compile and link with this:

```
nasm -f elf64 ex.asm
ld -lc -lm -m elf_x86_64 -I/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ex.o -o ex
```

Taking this opportunity, I will ask you, where I can read a spec to C calling convention in x86_64 linux? I know that it is an fastcall, but i can't understand a thinness like this.

Comment: Probably because the call requires stack alignment. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691792/how-to-write-assembly-language-hello-world-program-for-64-bit-mac-os-x

Comment: Also, (and I might have told you this already) if you use libc you should use `main` as entry point and `gcc` to link, so that the proper initialization happens. Similarly, don't use the exit syscall just return from `main` or call the `exit` libc function if you really must.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324333/does-printf-require-additional-stack-space-on-the-x86-64