# Calling C function in assembly code (gas)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I found an example and was editing it for gas.

```
extern printf
.global _start
.data
hello:
db "Hello", 0xa, 0
.text
_start:
mov %rdi, hello
mov %rax, 0
call printf
mov %rax, 0
ret
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong? What does this mean:

```
    hello:
db "Hello", 0xa, 0
```

I understand what it scope of memory, but I don't understand this string

```
db "Hello", 0xa, 0
```

And here

```
_start:
mov %rdi, hello
mov %rax, 0
call printf
mov %rax, 0
ret
```

os: linux (debian). intel 64-bit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691792/how-to-write-assembly-language-hello-world-program-for-64-bit-mac-os-x-using-pri?lq=1

Comment: `db` is a NASM directive.  In GAS you want `.asciiz "Hello\n"`.  Also, AT&T syntax is `mov $0, %eax`, with the destination last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's is the [**null-byte-terminattor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). Well-know as C-string.Such byte at end-of-string say where the string ends. For example,you pass the pointer to your string to call a routine,the routine will understand that the area of such string on memory is from begging `a[0]`(in C terminology) until `a[x] == 0` is seen.

Answer (score 0):

All that does is place bytes into the program. The bytes are the characters "Hello", followed by 0xa (which is the line termination), and finally a NULL byte. In C it would be something like "char *hello = "Hello\n";"

At your _start: label, you place the address of the `hello` label into register %rdi, you place 0 into %rax, and you call the `printf` function.

Answer (score 0):

The following declares a string with Hello followed by a line feed and null terminator.  The null terminator is required for C strings

```
db "Hello", 0xa, 0
```

To call printf, you need to pass the parameter on the stack so it would be something like

```
mov hello, (%esp)
call printf
```

As far as I know, the convention is mov source, destination.  You seem to have coded it the other way round.

Comment: Using `rdi` for the first argument is correct on a 64-bit Linux/UNIX. Windows on x86-64 uses `rcx, rdx, r8` and `r9` for the first four integer/pointer arguments, and the stack for the rest. Linux/UNIX uses `rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8` and `r9` for the first six arguments. The source/destination order does look reversed though if this is supposed to be AT&T syntax code.

Comment: In 32-bit code it would be `push $hello` to push the address as an immediate.  You don't want to load bytes from the string, and `mov` from memory to memory isn't allowed anyway.  In 64-bit code, `lea hello(%rdi), %rdi`.