# Calling printf in x86_64 using GNU assembler

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I've written a program using AT&T syntax for use with GNU assembler:

```
            .data
format:   .ascii "%d\n"  

            .text
            .global main  
main:
            mov    $format, %rbx
            mov    (%rbx), %rdi
            mov    $1, %rsi
            call     printf
            ret
```

I use *GCC* to assemble and link with:

> gcc -o main main.s

I run it with this command:

> ./main

When I run the program I get a seg fault. By using gdb, it says `printf` not found. I have tried ".extern printf", which does not work. Someone suggested I should store the stack pointer before calling `printf` and restore before *RET*, How do I do that?

Comment: You should *really* read up on the SysV x86-64 ABI. At a glance, you misalign the stack before the call, you don't zero `%rax`, you don't use the right registers for the right arguments and I suspect you're dereferencing `format` when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are a number of issues with this code. The [AMD64 System V ABI](https://web.archive.org/web/20160801075139/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) calling convention used by Linux requires a few things. It requires that just before a *CALL* that the stack be at least 16-byte (or 32-byte) aligned:

> The end of the input argument area shall be aligned on a 16 (32, if __m256 is
> passed on stack) byte boundary.

After the *C* runtime calls your `main` function the stack is misaligned by 8 because the return pointer was placed on the stack by *CALL*. To realign to 16-byte boundary you can simply *PUSH* **any** general purpose register onto the stack and *POP* it off at the end.

The calling convention also requires that *AL* contain the number of vector registers used for a variable argument function:

> %al is used to indicate the number of vector arguments passed to a function requiring a variable number of arguments

`printf` is a variable argument function, so *AL* needs to be set. In this case you don't pass any parameters in a vector register so you can set *AL* to 0.

You also dereference the $format pointer when it is already an address. So this is wrong:

```
mov  $format, %rbx
mov  (%rbx), %rdi
```

This takes the address of format and places it in *RBX*. Then you take the 8 bytes at that address in *RBX* and place them in *RDI*. *RDI* needs to be a *pointer* to a string of characters, not the characters themselves. The two lines could be replaced with:

```
lea  format(%rip), %rdi
```

This uses RIP Relative Addressing.

You should also *NUL* terminate your strings. Rather than use `.ascii` you can use `.asciz` on the x86 platform.

A working version of your program could look like:

```
# global data  #
    .data
format: .asciz "%d\n"
.text
    .global main
main:
  push %rbx
  lea  format(%rip), %rdi
  mov  $1, %esi           # Writing to ESI zero extends to RSI.
  xor %eax, %eax          # Zeroing EAX is efficient way to clear AL.
  call printf
  pop %rbx
  ret
```

---

## Other Recommendations/Suggestions

You should also be aware from the 64-bit Linux ABI, that the calling convention also requires functions you write to honor the preservation of certain registers. The list of registers and whether they should preserved is as follows:

[image]

Any register that says `Yes` in the *Preserved across
function calls* column are ones you must ensure are preserved across your function. Function `main` is like any other *C* function.

---

If you have strings/data that you know will be read only you can place them in the `.rodata` section with `.section .rodata` rather than `.data`

---

In 64-bit mode: if you have a destination operand that is a 32-bit register, the CPU will zero extend the register across the entire 64-bit register. This can save bytes on the instruction encoding.

---

It is possible your executable is being compiled as position independent code. You may receive an error similar to:

> relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

To fix this you'll have to call the external function `printf` this way:

```
call printf@plt
```

This calls the external library function via the [Procedure Linkage Table (PLT)](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1993)

Comment: I have reorganized my code and it works. I thought it was a problem of import printf, which is not necessary. Thanks so much.

Comment: In this particular code example since there is only one call and it appears at the end one can JMP to `printf` rather than _CALL_ and eliminate the stack alignment with the PUSH/POP. That was outside the scope of my answer but one can always look at literature on [TAIL CALL optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#In_assembly)

Comment: Excellent recommendations.  Future travelers, see also: https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2014/04/18/lets-write-some-x86-64/

Comment: The changelog message from my edit contains the important points.  .  The ABI doc link is broken.  The other changes are optional, because `xor %eax,%eax` is the best way to set AL or RAX to zero (so it's not harmful to say that variadic functions look at `%rax` instead of `%al`), and the rest were just extra details / comments I made since an edit was needed anyway to fix the ABI link.

Answer (score 6):

You can look at assembly code generated from an equivalent c file.
Running `gcc -o - -S -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables test.c` with test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   return printf("%d\n", 1);
}
```

This output the assembly code:

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "%d\n"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $1, %esi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        popq    %rbp
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.1.1 20160602"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

This give you a sample of an assembly code calling printf that you can then modify.

---

Comparing with your code, you should modify 2 things:

- %rdi should point to the format, you should not unreferenced %rbx, this could be done with `mov  $format, %rdi`
- printf has a variable number of arguments, then you should add `mov  $0, %eax`

Applying these modifications will give something like :

```
    .data
format: .ascii "%d\n"  
.text
    .global main  
main:
  mov  $format, %rdi
  mov  $1, %rsi
  mov  $0, %eax
  call printf
  ret
```

And then running it print :

> 1

Comment: Your modified code doesn't 16-byte align the stack before the call to`printf`. It may work in many scenarios but not all. Pushing any 64-bit register after your function `main` starts and restoring it at the end would keep things aligned. The 64-bit Linux ABI requires a minimum 16-byte alignment (32-byte aligned if passing 256 bit vectors to a function). At the point just before a function call the stack needs 16(or 32) byte alignment. After the _CALL_ instruction transfers control to a function (`main` is like other _C_ function)the return address is placed on the stack misaligning it by 8.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I tried to give a working code with minimal modification, otherwise the gcc generated assembly is better.

Comment: Unfortunately the 16-byte alignment is lucky to be working code in this case. I would suspect that on an optimization level like -O2 or higher it would actually remove the PUSH/POP/RET and then do a tail call JMP to `printf`. In that case alignment is still maintained (without the extra PUSH/POP) since JMP doesn't place a return address  on the stack like a CALL.

Comment: Michael is correct: gcc emits optimal code if you ask it to optimize (by using `-O3`):  https://godbolt.org/g/sX5yCe.  It uses a `jmp` for the tail-call so the stack alignment stays the same as on entry to `main`.  It also uses `xor` to zero `%al`, instead of a less-efficient `mov`.  And of course it puts the string constant in `.rodata`, not `.data`.  Using compiler output as a starting-point for optimization is a good plan, but only if you start with `-O2` or `-O3` output!  Otherwise you might do worse than the compiler.