# Calling C function from x64 assembly with registers instead of stack

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, gnu-assembler

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591121/2079797) puzzled me.

According to the [standard C calling conventions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions), the standard way to call C functions is to `push` arguments to the stack and to `call` the subroutine. That is clearly different from [syscalls](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/), where you set different registers with appropriate arguments and then `syscall`.

However, the answer mentioned above gives this GAS code:

```
        .global main
        .section .data
hello:  .asciz "Hello\n"
        .section .text
main:
        movq $hello, %rdi
        movq $0, %rax
        call printf
        movq $0, %rax
        ret
```

which works with `gcc hello.s -o hello`. The part that calls `printf` is:

```
        movq $hello, %rdi
        movq $0, %rax
        call printf
```

It is using the `rdi` register, not the stack, to pass the argument to `printf`. Changing the above to

```
        push $hello
        call printf
```

causes segmentation fault.

Since `printf` is a C function, unlike `sys_write`, I think the arguments should be passed to the stack, not the registers. What am I misunderstanding here? What about other standard C functions, such as `malloc`?

(Any reference would be truly appreciated.)

Comment: A "convention" is not a "standard". The things are different in the 64-bit world. Take a look at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions).

Comment: same problem as you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193786/calling-from-c-functions-written-in-nasm-on-x86-64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing arguments to variadic functions is more complicated. See [x86-64 ELF ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf), section 3.5.7. Otherwise, x86-64 passes its first 6 arguments using registers: `%rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8, %r9` (excluding float / vector arguments).

From the specification, `%rax = 0` means that the variable argument list has no (0) floating-point arguments passed in vector registers. Your approach is wrong, as the first argument (e.g., the nul-terminated string: `"Hello\n"`) must be passed in `%rdi`, and `%rax` must be zero when the function is called.

Comment: This is precisely what I have been looking for. Thank you so much.