# Mix Assembly and C function in linux kernel - x64 mode

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, calling-convention

I am learning assembly language and I create a simple linux kernel module to try how to call an assembly function from module, which in turns call a C function.  The code compiles fine. However, when I try to insert the module, it causes kernel crash.  I get the idea from this post: [Calling C functions from x86 assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255608/calling-c-functions-from-x86-assembly-language).  I am wondering whether anybody can help me understand why it doesn't work.

The first is assembly code:

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>
ENTRY(sample_assembly_function)
pushq $10
call printMessage
add $0x4, %rsp
END(sample_assembly_function)
```

The second file is sample module file:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Proprietary");

void sample_assembly_function(void);

void printMessage(int num)
{
 printk(KERN_ERR "MixAssemblyAndC: PrintMessage=%d.\n", num);
}

static int __init AModule_init(void)
{
sample_assembly_function();
return 0;
}

static void __exit AModule_exit(void)
{
printk("MixAssemblyAndC: Goodbye, world!\n");
}

module_init(AModule_init);
module_exit(AModule_exit);
```

And finally this is Makefile:

```
KERNELDIR:=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD=$(shell pwd)
obj-m += test.o
test-y := AModule.o ASample.o

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD)

clean:
     $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean

install:
     $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install
```

Comment: The x64 calling convention is not at all the same as the x86 calling convention.  Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28601779/12711 and/or https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.2130-001/x64-intro.pdf

Comment: I agree with Michael and one other obvious issue is that you push an 8 byte value and then only adjust RSP by 4 after (and not 8)

Comment: You are definitely going to need a debugger when you're just learning asm.  You can learn *much* more from seeing register values and single-stepping than you can from just a crash.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/dev-tools/kgdb.html

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestion.  There are some good reference points!  @MichaelPetch Please see my comments to your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the [Linux 64-bit System V ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) calling convention you pass the first 6 integer class or pointer arguments in the registers *RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8*, and *R9*. Any remaining parameters are pushed on the stack. The code you linked to in your question is 32-bit code and that uses the [Linux i386 System V ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf) as a calling convention. That is not compatible with 64-bit code.

Simply do `mov $10, %rdi` to load the first parameter. Preferably you can do `mov $10, %edi`. The latter moves the value 10 into EDI but since the target is a 32-bit register the processor automatically zero extends the value across the 64-bit register thus 10 is moved to RDI. The latter is a shorter encoding.

You need a `ret` instruction to end your assembly language routine. The resulting code should look like:

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>

ENTRY(sample_assembly_function)
mov $10, %edi
call printMessage
ret
END(sample_assembly_function)
```

Since the `call` is the last thing before `ret` you can also just `jmp printMessage` ([Tail Call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)). When the `ret` in `printMessage` is reached, control will return to the function that called `sample_assembly_function`. This code should work:

```
ENTRY(sample_assembly_function)
mov $10, %edi
jmp printMessage
END(sample_assembly_function)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It does help me solve the problem.  Thanks.  I have another question though:  I added a new function which just try to add 2 numbers (pass 2 integers as arguments) then printk the result.  Exactly same scenario as my original question.  The Add2Numbers function is defined in the same C file and then I try to call it from the same assembly file (instead of calling the PrintMessage).  However, I get this compiling warning:  WARNING: "Add2Numbers" [/home/bob/MixAssemblyAndC/test.ko] undefined!  Any suggestion?

Comment: @iceheart You could ask a new question with the code that is failing with that error

Comment: Sorry.  It is my fault.  I will be more diligent on following up with my own questions.  Thanks for the answer. I can accept it as answer for my question.

Comment: I guess you are right I may have a typo.  It is working now.