# How can I print the sum to the screen in assembly in this code?

Tags: linux, assembly

How can i write the output to the screen?

```
 SECTION .data
 x:
   dd 1
   dd 5
   dd 2
   dd 18
 sum:
   dd 0
 SECTION .text
  mov eax,4 ; EAX will serve as a counter
  mov ebx,0 ; EBX will store the sum
  mov ecx, x ; ECX will point to the current
 top:
  add ebx, [ecx]
  add ecx,4 ; move pointer to next element
  dec eax ; decrement counter
  jnz top ; if counter not 0, then loop again
 done:
  mov [sum],ebx ; done, store result in "sum"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194141/how-to-print-a-number-in-assembly-nasm

Comment: Some discussion here: http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1514.0

Comment: The links that you have given have information for 32 bit system but I use 64 bit system so can you tell me how I can compile those for 64 bit?

Comment: I'm still running 32-bit hardware, so I'd be guessing. I would have guessed(!) that your `mov ecx, x` would cause ld (not Nasm) to barf with a "relocation truncated to fit". Perhaps not. Shortly after upgrading to 64-bit, I might have an answer for ya. :)

Comment: Compiling for x86_64: `nasm -f elf64 yourapp.asm` and then use the usual `ld yourapp.o -o yourapp` linker command.

Comment: I have solved my problem, thank you. All i needed was to install multilib to run 32-bit code under 64-bit.