# How to print the length of a string in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am learning assembly using the following hello world program

```
section .text
    global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:             ;tells linker entry point
   mov  edx,len     ;message length
   mov  ecx,msg     ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   mov  eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
    msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our string
    len equ $ - msg              ;length of our string
```

The original question I had was what is meant by the length of the string. Does it mean the number of chars or the length in memory (number of bytes)?
To check this I wanted to print the variable len. How can I do that? I naively tried to define the new variable

```
    len2 equ $ - len
```

and then instead run

```
   mov  edx,len2     ;message length
   mov  ecx,len     ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel
```

to try to print len, but this printed nothing. How can I print the number that is represented by len?

Comment: You may want to check [**How to print a number in assembly NASM?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194141/how-to-print-a-number-in-assembly-nasm) The short answer is you write *characters* to `stdout`. A number is a decimal value, not a string of characters you can immediately write, you must convert the integer or unsigned value to its character representation, then write it to `stdout`.

Comment: Out of curiosity what OS are you programming for? Windows? Unix? MacOS? i'm asking because on top of questions like this often people asking on SO are using tutorials for the wrong platform.

Comment: Thanks. I am using ubuntu. Out of curiosity, when I try to print the number using stdout directly, I get nothing. Why does it print nothing at all instead of printing some nonsense ?

Comment: Because the SYS_write system call prints string not numbers. You have to convert the numbers to a string and print the string. you could also choose to use the _C_ library and use things like `printf` to print numbers. `printf` will do the number to string conversions for you, otherwise you have to code it yourself.

Comment: @JonathanLindgren: You're passing a number which `SYS_write` tries to use as a pointer, so it returns `-EFAULT`.  (System calls on bad pointers return errors instead of raising SIGSEGV.)  Use a debugger, and/or `strace`.  See the bottom of [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
   ...
   mov  edx,len     ;message length
```

This loads `edx` with some kind of numeric value, like 14 in this case. `len` is "equ" constant symbol, something like `#define` in C.

```
   mov  ecx,msg     ;message to write
```

This loads `ecx` with address of first character (`msg` is label, pointing into memory).

```
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel
   ...

    msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our string
```

This defines 14 bytes of memory, with values 72 ('H'), 101 ('e'), ... . The first byte is pointed at by `msg` label (memory address of it).

```
    len equ $ - msg              ;length of our string
```

This defines constant `len` visible during compile time. It doesn't define any memory content, so you can't find it in the executable or during runtime (unless used, like by that `mov edx,len`, then it is compiled into that particular instruction of course).

The definition is `$ - msg`, the `$` in this context works as "current address", where the next defined machine code byte will be compiled, so at this place it is equal to `msg + 14` (I hope I did count the number of characters correctly :) ). And `((msg+14) - msg) = 14` = number of bytes defined in the memory between the definition of `len` and label `msg`.

Notice how I avoid words as variable or chars, the ASM is more low level, so labels into memory and bytes is more accurate wording and I hope it will help you to recognize the subtle differences.

Your `len2 equ $ - len` after the `len` did thus define value `len2` as `(msg+14)` (still there in the memory, no new byte added by `len` definition) minus `len` which is `14`, so you effectively defined `len2` equal to `msg`.

Then:

```
   mov  edx,len2     ;message length
   mov  ecx,len     ;message to write
   ...
```

Does call `sys_write` with pointer to string equal to `14` (invalid memory reference, that area of memory is off limits to ordinary user code), and length equal to address `msg`, which will be on 32b linux very likely some value like `0x80004000`, i.e. over 2G of characters to output.

The `sys_write` naturally doesn't like that, fails, and returns error code in `eax`.

To output anything to console with `sys_write` you have to first write it into memory as ASCII (I think UTF8 is supported by default in Ubuntu shell, but too lazy to verify) encoded string, and give the `sys_write` address of that memory, and length in bytes (with UTF8 string the difference between bytes and chars is important, `sys_write` is not aware of characters, it works with binary files and bytes, so the length is amount of bytes).

I'm not going to write code to output numbers, as that's several lines long (simplified `printf` implementation) and SO has several Q+A over this, but I hope my explanation will help you to understand what happened and how it works.

If you are just learning ASM, consider either linking against `clib` to have `printf` available, or even better, use debugger, and verify the values straight in registers in debugger, don't bother with string output yet, that's a bit more advanced topic then the initial arithmetic, and basic flow control and operating stack. After you will be more comfortable with how basic instruction works, and how to debug the code, it will be more easier to try to output numbers then.

Comment: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13166064) has a couple examples of how to generate an ASCII string of base-10 digits and pass that to a `write` system call.