# NASM Linux shared object error: Relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.data'

Tags: linux, linker, x86-64, nasm

I am compiling a NASM 64-bit shared object in Linux using the NASM compiler and linking with ld.  It compiles to an object file using the following string:

```
sudo nasm -felf64 Test_File.asm
```

I link with ld:

```
sudo ld -shared Test_File.o -o Test_File.so
```

and I get the following errors:

```
Relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
```

Unfortunately, the NASM compiler does not have a -fPIC option.

After reading many resources on writing position-independent code for 64-bit shared libraries in Linux, I understand the issue very well, but I still don't have a clear idea of what instruction changes I need to make to be position-independent in 64-bit NASM.  For example, do all instructions involving named variables need to be "rel" -- for example, movsd xmm0,[rel abc] instead of movsd xmm0,[abc]?  I know that R_X86_64_32S indicates 32-bit addressing, but I don't have any 32-bit addressing in my  code.

Also, there are significant differences between 32-bit and 64-bit on how position independent code is written, and some of the resources concentrate only on 32-bit code.  Even Section 9.2 Writing NetBSD/FreeBSD/OpenBSD and Linux/ELF Shared Libraries in the NASM manual is not clear on how 64-bit code must be altered for position-independent code.  That section focuses on 32-bit code (using the global offset table), which is not (based on other research) used for 64-bit code.

1. The file is headed with [BITS 64] and [default rel], as required.
2. The data section is declared as section .data align=16
3. Every variable in the .data section is defined as dq, for example,   number: dq 0.
4. The top of the file contains the exports in this format:  global ABC:function.

I suspect that only data movement instructions would be affected -- math instructions would not.  For the external calls to realloc, I added the wrt ..plt special symbol, but I still get the same errors.

Here are my questions:

1. Do all mov instructions need to be rewritten with the "rel" keyword, for example, mov rax,[rel abc]  instead of mov rax,[abc]?
2. Do lea instructions need to be changed (e.g., lea rdi,[rel abc])?
3. Are there any other instruction types that need special handling?

I am not posting the entire (very long) nasm code listing here because I'm not looking for line-by-line analysis.  I just want to know what instruction types (for example, mov, cmp, jmp, lea) need to be rewritten for 64-bit relative addressing, and how.  Does it involve only accesses to variables defined in the data section (e.g., mov rcx,[abc] where abc is defined in the data section as abc: dq 0).

To summarize, my question is: what changes do I need to make for position-independent code for 64-bit NASM, since the NASM compiler does not have a fPIC option?   I certainly don't mean line-by-line, but what types of instructions need to be added or rewritten.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the NASM compiler does not have a -fPIC option.

Of course not; that's a code-gen option for a *compiler*.  NASM is an assembler, not a compiler; the instructions it assembles are set by the source file, not command-line options.  (The error message is assuming people are using `ld` on compiler output, not hand-written asm.)

Recompile = redo generating the asm instructions, not reassemble the same asm with different options.  The compiler is your brain.

---

> 1. Do all mov instructions need to be rewritten with the "rel" keyword

**No, you can just use `default rel`** at the top of your file like a normal person instead of modifying every addressing mode to explicitly use `[rel foo]`.

> 2. and 3. Are there any other instruction types that need special handling?

It's nothing to do with the `mov` instruction, everything to do with the addressing mode.  All instructions (including LEA) use the same ModR/M + optional SIB + disp0/8/32 encoding for addressing modes.  (Except for one form of `mov` which can use a 64-bit absolute address when loading/storing AL/AX/EAX/RAX.  But you don't want that either.)

You also need to **avoid any use of addresses as 32-bit absolute immediate operands**.  So if you're putting an address into a register, you need a RIP-relative LEA instead of the more efficient 5-byte mov-immediate that you could use in position-dependent code.

```
;; putting a label address into a register
default rel
    mov edi, my_string     ; optimal in position-dependent executables on Linux
    lea rdi, [my_string]   ; optimal otherwise, best you can do for PIC/PIE

    mov rdi, my_string     ; Never use: 64-bit absolute is inefficient
```

The only time you should use 64-bit absolute addresses is in `.data` or `.rodata` for the contents of a jump table or other pointers to static addresses.  Not in code; use RIP-relative instead.

---

Obviously you have to avoid `[disp32 + reg]` addressing modes like `[array + rdi]` or `[array + rdx*4]`.  **The only RIP-relative addressing mode is `[RIP + rel32]`**; other modes still use the 32-bit displacement as a sign-extended 32-bit absolute value (so it can be a constant offset like 1024, not an address at all).

[Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300844/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm-accessing) (MachO64 never allows 32-bit absolute, so it's the same restrictions as a Linux/ELF PIC object)

> I know that R_X86_64_32S indicates 32-bit addressing, but I don't have any 32-bit addressing in my code.

`[abs foo]` is a disp32 sign-extended to 64.  That's why the relocation type is 32**S**.  By contrast, `mov edi, foo` uses `R_X86_64_32`.

It's not 32-bit address-size, but the absolute address still has to be encoded as a 32-bit signed integer.  Which isn't allowed in a PIE/PIC object which has to be relocatable anywhere in 64-bit address space.

---

Related:

- [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) (about PIE vs. non-PIE executables, but still has useful comments about 32-bit absolute addresses)
- [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300844/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm-accessing)
- [How to print a number in assembly NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194141/how-to-print-a-number-in-assembly-nasm/32853546#32853546) shows how to call libc functions from NASM PIE/PIC code, through the PLT or `gcc -fno-plt` style with `call [rel printf wrt ..got]`

---

PIC libraries are expected to support symbol interposition.  See [Sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20171111043629/http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/) for more.

**If you want efficient internal access to your own `global` symbols  (without going through GOT)**, you may need to define weak aliases for them that have "hidden" ELF visibility.  Or simply put 2 labels at the same place, one global one hidden.  See [7.9.5 elf Extensions to the GLOBAL Directive](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.5) in the NASM manual:

```
   global   hashlookup:function hidden
```

Also, the NASM manual notes:

> Declaring the type and size of global symbols is necessary when writing shared library code. For more information, see section 9.2.4.