# Error linking a Linux shared library in NASM - 'readdressing R_X86_64_PC32 to symbol "foo"'

Tags: c, assembly, shared-libraries, x86-64, nasm

I am currently re-coding some functions from the standard C library in NASM x64. At the moment I only have two functions:

**strlen**:

```
bits 64

section .text
    global  strlen
        strlen:
            xor rbx, rbx
            jmp strlen_loop

        strlen_loop:
            cmp byte [rdi + rbx], 0
            je strlen_ret
            inc rbx
            jmp strlen_loop

        strlen_ret:
            mov rax, rbx
            ret
```

**putstr**:

```
bits 64

extern strlen

STDOUT equ 1

section .text
    global putstr
        putstr:
            call strlen
            mov rdx, rax
            xor rax, rax
            mov rdi, STDOUT
            syscall
            ret
```

Here is the makefile:

```
CC      =   nasm
CFLAGS  =   -f elf64
SRC     =   $(wildcard src/*.asm)
OBJ     =   $(SRC:.asm=.o)
NAME    =   minilibc.so

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    ld -fPIC -shared -o $(NAME) $(OBJ) -nostdlib

%.o: %.asm
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

test: re
    gcc -o test/test test/main.c
    LD_PRELOAD=./minilibc.so ./test/test

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

and the test code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern size_t putstr(const char *str);

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "Hello, World!\n";
    putstr(str);
    return (0);
}
```

Here's the error I get:

> ```
> rm -f src/putstr.o src/strlen.o
> rm -f minilibc.so
> nasm -f elf64 src/putstr.asm -o src/putstr.o
> nasm -f elf64 src/strlen.asm -o src/strlen.o
> ld -fPIC -shared -o minilibc.so src/putstr.o src/strlen.o -nostdlib
> ld: src/putstr.o: attention: readdress on "strlen" in read-only ".text" section
> ld: src/putstr.o: readdressing R_X86_64_PC32 to symbol "strlen" cannot be used when creating a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
> ld: final link edit failed: wrong value
> make: *** [Makefile:10: minilibc.so] Error 1
> ```

LD seems to be telling me to recompile in PIC mode, which I'm already doing, so is the problem that my functions have the same name as the GLIBC functions? However, I'm compiling without the standard library.

Comment: Please read [the nasm documentation about building for 64-bit systems](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10.07/html/nasmdo11.html), read about what it says about position independent code.

Comment: And what is the reason you do this in assembler? What is your actual problem? Your actual assignment? Your actual goal?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm doing this for practice (but that's not the point) and my problem is that I get a compile error in shared library mode. I will read this doc thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `global strlen:function hidden` instead of `global strlen`** to make the symbol visible to the linker so other object files can reference it, but *not* exported from the `.so` shared object we're making so it doesn't participate in symbol interposition.

Or to allow efficient calls inside the library but still export the symbol outside, define a second label at the same place, like `strlen_internal: strlen:` and make the internal one `hidden` but the other one just normal `global strlen:function` non-hidden.  I don't know of a better way to do this, to get `ld` to make calls to a visibility=default symbol only go to the definition inside this shared object.

---

**Your `global strlen` makes the symbol fully global, participating in symbol interposition.**  The linker won't let you reference that symbol with a `call rel32` since the actual definition that gets used at dynamic link time might be in a different shared library (for example `libc.so` since you used the name of a standard C function), and it might be loaded more than +- 2GiB away from this shared library.

In 32-bit code, a rel32 can reach anywhere in virtual address-space, so "re-addressing" (like a text relocation) could handle it with just the warning about needing to rewrite the machine code in a read-only page (in `.text`).

---

In this case you don't want to let your library call a faster version of `strlen` if the dynamic linker has already seen one in a different library. Your `putstr` depends on custom behaviour of your `strlen` that the ABI doesn't require (e.g. not modifying the RDI pointer arg so you have it available after finding the length, without saving/restoring anything on the stack).

Your `strlen` is also not ABI-compatible with compiler-generated code; it modifies the caller's RBX, which is a call-preserved register in standard x86-64 calling conventions.  But that's a problem even when it's called from `putstr` since that eventually returns to a C caller.  Just use RAX in the first place, instead of a separate register that you later copy to the return value.  Or count into RDX since this private version of `strlen` only exists as a helper for `putstr`.  (Maybe call it a different name, too.)

Your `putstr` is also just plain broken, BTW; it doesn't copy RDI to RSI for the `void*` arg to `write`, and actually makes a `read` system call not `write`.  (The system call numbers match the standard file descriptor, e.g. `__NR_write = STDOUT_FD = 1` in `unistd_64.h` for x86-64 Linux, this is a helpful choice for remembering them.)  Presumably you'd notice that if you tried this not in a shared library so you could get it working linked into an executable.  Or if you put your `strlen` in the same `.asm` as `putstr` and made it not `global`.

---

Related:

- https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.9.5 - `elf` Extensions to the `GLOBAL` Directive documents this.
- [Call a function in another object file without using PLT within a shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573771/call-a-function-in-another-object-file-without-using-plt-within-a-shared-library) GAS version of the same problem.  In GAS, you'd do `.globl strlen` and `.hidden strlen`.  And IIRC, `.type strlen, @function`
- [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code) - three ways to call functions in *other* shared libraries: PLT, `gcc -fno-plt` style, or make a non-PIE executable so the linker invents indirection via the PLT for you.  The example at the bottom of linkers "relaxing" calls from indirect/PLT to direct mentions NASM's `hidden` flag.
- [NASM Linux shared object error: Relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106310/nasm-linux-shared-object-error-relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-data) also mentions NASM's `hidden` flag for the `global` directive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you probably noticed I'm a beginner in NASM x64, so I had a few questions about your answer:

1. As my project is to recode my version of GLIBC (for training purposes), how can I ensure that strlen can be called everywhere and not just for internal functions?

2. How can I make a call to functions of my own creation that will also be liked in the shared object? (And with the same name as the GLIBC functions).

Comment: @VirgilG.: As mentioned in [Call a function in another object file without using PLT within a shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51573771) , you can create two labels at the same position: one for calls from within the library, and one exported.  Like maybe `strlen_internal:` and `strlen:`.  I don't know if there's a cleaner way to do this efficiently.  The inefficient way is to make calls even within the library go through the PLT or GOT, like `call [rel strlen wrt ..got]` the same as you'd use from another shared library, as shown in that YASM / standard library Q&A.

Comment: "... it modifies RBX, which is a call-clobbered register." Shouldn't this better read "call-preserved register (callee-saved register)" I know it depends a lot on how the whole sentence is read and understood, but I keep finding it strange.

Comment: @SepRoland: That was just a brain-fart on my part; I was already thinking about what I was going to write next (pick a call-clobbered register instead).  Thanks for catching mistakes like that in my answers; we know what I meant, but beginners could easily be confused since they don't already understand the subject, so it's important to fix stuff like that!