# How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)

Tags: assembly, x86, integer, output, nasm

Can anyone tell me the *purely assembly* code for displaying the value in a register in decimal format? Please don't suggest using the printf hack and then compile with gcc.

Description:

Well, I did some research and some experimentation with NASM and figured I could use the printf function from the c library to print an integer. I did so by compiling the object file with the GCC compiler and everything works fair enough.

However, what I want to achieve is to print the value stored in any register in the decimal form.

I did some research and figured the interrupt vector 021h for DOS command line can display strings and characters whilst either 2 or 9 is in the ah register and the data is in the dx.

Conclusion:

None of the examples I found showed how to display the content value of a register in decimal form without using the C library's printf.  Does anyone know how to do this in assembly?

Comment: What kind of number is it?  Floating point?

Comment: For simplicity sake, lets assume its an unsigned integer.

Say I've got 00000101h in dh

how do i get to display 5?

Say I've got 00000111h in dh

how do i get to display 7?

Comment: Im using NASM on Windows 7 (x86) and I'm using the default "com" output format!

Comment: It seems to me that **"any register"** in your message is slightly incorrect. Probably you mean **any general register**? Eg. `ip`/`eip` can not be addressed directly in 16-bit / 32-bit x86 assembly (however, `rip` can be addressed directly in 64-bit x86-64 assembly). More important matter is that you don't say if you want to print the number as signed or unsigned. And also please note that printing 8-bit number (such as `dh`) is different than printing 16-bit (such as `dx`) or 32-bit (such as `edx`) number. In assembly, these kind of differences really matter.

Comment: You're not going to get any DOS .com programs to run on W7 without some kind of virtualization.

Comment: @nrz - Yes I should have specifically mentioned general purpose registers. And, yes I'm aware of the 8 bit registers, the 16 bit registers and the extended 32 bit ones which have an e prefix. Thanks for pointing out though. :)

Comment: @JensBjörnhager Im using nasm to assemble the com file and then "call" the com file via the Command Propmt (16 bit MS-DOS prompt) which is available in Windows 7 inside the System32 folder.

Comment: A DOS 16-bit version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244624/print-integer-to-console-in-x86-assembly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Outputting integers in assembly on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031831/outputting-integers-in-assembly-on-linux)

Answer (score 22):

You need to write a binary to decimal conversion routine, and then use the decimal digits to produce "digit characters" to print.

You have to assume that something, somewhere, will print a character on your output device of choice.  Call this subroutine "print_character"; assumes it takes a character code in EAX and preserves all the registers..   (If you don't have such a subroutine, you have an additional problem that should be the basis of a different question).

If you have the binary code for a digit (e.g.,  a value from 0-9) in a register (say, EAX), you can convert that value to a character for the digit by adding the ASCII code for the "zero" character to the register.   This is as simple as:

```
       add     eax, 0x30    ; convert digit in EAX to corresponding character digit
```

You can then call print_character to  print the digit character code.

To output an arbitrary value, you need to pick off digits and print them.

Picking off digits fundamentally requires working with powers of ten.   It is easiest to work with one power of ten, e.g., 10 itself.    Imagine we have a divide-by-10 routine that took a value in EAX, and produced a quotient in EDX and a remainder in EAX.  I leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to implement such a routine.

Then a simple routine with the right idea is to produce one digit for all digits the value might have.   A 32 bit register stores values to 4 billion, so you might get 10 digits printed.  So:

```
         mov    eax, valuetoprint
         mov    ecx, 10        ;  digit count to produce
loop:    call   dividebyten
         add    eax, 0x30
         call   printcharacter
         mov    eax, edx
         dec    ecx
         jne    loop
```

This works... but prints the digits in reverse order.  Oops!  Well, we can take advantage of the pushdown stack to store digits produced, and then pop them off in reverse order:

```
         mov    eax, valuetoprint
         mov    ecx, 10        ;  digit count to generate
loop1:   call   dividebyten
         add    eax, 0x30
         push   eax
         mov    eax, edx
         dec    ecx
         jne    loop1
         mov    ecx, 10        ;  digit count to print
loop2:   pop    eax
         call   printcharacter
         dec    ecx
         jne    loop2
```

Left as an exercise to the reader:  suppress leading zeros.   Also, since we are writing digit characters to memory, instead of writing them to the stack we could write them to a buffer, and then print the buffer content.  Also left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Is this actually faster than `call    _printf`?

Comment: @XStylish: Probably: If by printf you mean a method that takes a format string and formats a decimal numbers, surely, because the printf routine will have to interpret the format string as well as produce the digits, and this only produces digits.  Speed probably doesn't matter if you intend to produce output for the screen bcause people read so slowly.  If you are writing
strings to a file, you mght want to multiply by ".1"  and take the fractinal aprase -rather than divide by 10.

Comment: ... should have been "multiply by fixed-point value for 0.1 and take the fractional part rather than divide by 10, to improve speed of conversion."

Answer (score 13):

**You need to turn a binary integer into a string/array of ASCII decimal digits manually.**  ASCII digits are represented by 1-byte integers in the range `'0'` (0x30) to `'9'` (0x39).  http://www.asciitable.com/

For power-of-2 bases like hex, see [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-number-to-hex)  Converting between binary and a power-of-2 base allows many more optimizations and simplifications because each group of bits maps separately to a hex / octal digit.

---

Most operating systems / environments don't have a system call that accepts integers and converts them to decimal for you.  You have to do that yourself before sending the bytes to the OS, or copying them to video memory yourself, or drawing the corresponding font glyphs in video memory...

By far the most efficient way is to make a single system call that does the whole string at once, because a system call that writes 8 bytes is basically the same cost as writing 1 byte.

This means we need a buffer, but that doesn't add to our complexity much at all.  2^32-1 is only 4294967295, which is only 10 decimal digits.  Our buffer doesn't need to be large, so we can just use the stack.

**The usual algorithm produces digits LSD-first (Least Significant Digit first).  Since printing order is MSD-first, we can just start at the end of the buffer and work backwards**.  For printing or copying elsewhere, just keep track of where it starts, and don't bother about getting it to the start of a fixed buffer.  No need to mess with push/pop to reverse anything, just produce it backwards in the first place.

```c
char *itoa_end(unsigned long val, char *p_end) {
  const unsigned base = 10;
  char *p = p_end;
  do {
    *--p = (val % base) + '0';
    val /= base;
  } while(val);                  // runs at least once to print '0' for val=0.

  // write(1, p,  p_end-p);
  return p;  // let the caller know where the leading digit is
}
```

gcc/clang do an excellent job, [using a magic constant multiplier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi) instead of `div` to divide by 10 efficiently.  ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27unsigned+long+mod10(unsigned+long+a+)+%7Breturn+a%2510%3B%7D%0A%0Achar+*itoa_end(unsigned+long+val,+char+*p_end)+%7B%0A++const+unsigned+base+%3D+10%3B%0A++char+*p+%3D+p_end%3B%0A++do+%7B%0A++++*--p+%3D+(val+%25+base)+%2B+!%270!%27%3B%0A++++val+/%3D+base%3B%0A++%7D+while(val)%3B%0A%0A++//+write(1,+p,++p_end-p)%3B%0A%0A++return+p%3B++//+let+the+caller+know+where+the+leading+digit+is%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,directives:%270%27,intel:%270%27),options:%27-xc++-std%3Dgnu11+-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dsandybridge+-fverbose-asm+-funroll-loops%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) for asm output).

This [code-review Q&A](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142842/integer-to-ascii-algorithm-x86-assembly) has a nice efficient NASM version of that which accumulates the string into an 8-byte register instead of into memory, ready store where you want the string to start without extra copying.

---

#### To handle signed integers:

Use this algorithm on the unsigned absolute value.  (`val = val<0 ? 0U-val : val;`, i.e. xor-zero / `sub` / `cmovs` which keeps the original value around; [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgMwAHKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEmakAA6oCoRODB7evgHBaRmOAuGRMSzxiVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BXEG2mPbFDI3NBKXRcQlJtk0tbXmdwQqTQxEjFWPVAJS2qF7EyOwcXgwZwJHoANT8qBARBKcAbmJrJgDsVhoAgqefp8SYBNsMdzEJn8bg0p2BADFTho5ABae60U4gQG0YGvN7PAAiJneOLeAHp8adIsBTkTkCxULcFKcAO4kADWNPioi8SlOsIAklEACoAfQAsty6cQmCkaURTtz%2BUKoqcIqdVIEAGynJgKFikU4KVDyghgDg01AM06StApACeeMJHJYYtUVFOjCYsXoNLeygAGk7VARGBkBDT%2BMRzl4/j9Tm5lIprUTg2rtZgUs0mH7Tlh5hFU1lTqgUglDGd45hVHhM0Z5YJMMAEpWFIc8bHFSRYQAvBK6okKLyxMmnClUmll04pYioWIu2gW07xAh%2BkMEBCGU6U274klNpe3CKkhQIEjz/vETKiWiw5OL04GP0MZDTgRS3ahJgMzB0hAJN%2Br2E9PAsLN9OmqCYPWBo3PSxAmvG1zVgkTacvqhpqrQOozr8h7xsqkiwrEhC5vmooMOgsIZO2WoKEw24VkwpwAEpvN6D6Lm%2Bqgtu2Y53AoAB0pofqcAoAPIAGpNrRdSMDcbwCpioa0FOTq0H%2BAEsWxHZamIi5bMACC5rQWAhpmcnEpgmBYGcNFeHmpq6rSx5psxpzsagWoKouqb9uqX4vju/HCdqinaQQ8mjpgVAFq6mBcRwGy0JwACsvB%2BBwWikKgnBuNY1jalsOxvuY/g8KQBCaNFGwfkw%2BmUBsDIgP4cVcRoTxxXFACc/gtXFZiSIEXSxRwki8CwEgaBopBJSlaUcLwCggKNxXJdFpBwLAMBQKtEBIGgLApHQCTkJQW07fQiTAPWYp7qgBB8HQ84zRAsQlaQuHMMQFqcIVz3NBaAmxNodTzYVW1sIIAkMFOj1YLEXjAG4Ygoe9vBYHaRjiAtpD4D89S3CBj0lnUYZ7ClMF9SlimxKKr0eFgj0EMeQ3cItVAGKdQl4JgtICfmSWFfwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6ho7o/j6IYxiZZY%2Bh4LEM2QBseZ9DNHCwgA6nDHICf4trNMgCDApiSrKrCWHwgbsJ2ikDq8FSCTHhm8AbLU9TOBArjTB0IREcM5SVHohSZAIvsh%2BkYcMIHoxVN0vQNAsEdcAn/1J4MscrPH8yDCnEyZ0sQerO7OW7HotKGAQnMEJyDD8CVMXxYlj2TYqKqW5IpzAMgyCnBAtMHAyaz97ghAkOCZgFWsvDzVoaxlZgFVjBA1UgHFo19QNpBDRvY2t5w02zUVjdLetm2oNtu1kBQECHdfKAGEYfKDwwDLXbQt2UA9aOfa9CNPSzK9H6f0HAAKBhJUG4M0aQ2hrDOSGtCpIxlqjFKGN07Yw1ilPGyACYAOJo9MmFMLRU0JrPOmCMNhMyYCzNmHMuYAN5sIU8gtpBMNFmoR6uhkhP1lpYawCslZu1SikdWnBta61hPrQ2OwTb%2BExMAQihACw7XQAoR22NiAuxxirNOns/DeyIvnMIRc46RyKFkfOoc%2BhZ2DqnD2fQBhTE8O0PQDiM4tFsasAuzjch%2B1zp40x2cJCl22OXVOlcQaiLrg3BaTcOAJX3mjNu5tO79l4f3V%2Bw9R74CICGfKXAZ4nziYvZeiRV76E4NvXeo1xqO0PrYY%2Bc9SqkBqnvPq/gW7JIac0jYy01rwA2igS%2BR09q33vsdEAwBOjJBoJ/BId0f4pT/m9BmgCXrfV%2Bv9cBl9gbVzBqstBmAoYwzhogxGmBkbAFQYjPAmNHCYNxqofGfpHoELRkQr6pCaYUIZlQ5mChWbs05owRhsh%2BbiCFuwpQnCJZ6F4SgOWNgybKwqWrLIGsJFGSkTbO0sjTZ4F2AYV8sJkCKQkho52eBXa6PcV7H2LiZj%2B3QF4%2BO1jLGMr9uykoQS7F6MccnTlbiejpwEE4xYZQzH2MFX4txCxWUhM2GEwWpBInV2ifXSa89KkJK6RNTg7cLZYW7r3U4nQuJmByePfJU9Cmz0bmvdpVTBrr1qQfKajS5qn36UMiZYyDojIfqdZg4p9xXTmV/e6j0VkAJWSA7ZayIEgwORDY5cCzkAOQSjMh6M7kYJxmjHBeC0bvNJorYh3y0a0z/JQvgAKgX0NBWsphELWHC3kDC8WKVdDSARaYfh8sUXCPRYGcROtsX60pVo6lOiKl0oMQy2VqcTGSuCanbl2QhXrqjjY3l3j53ivzge%2BVe6c4ytcdKwuq67GhNyhXKuNcYlasWn1RJdTUoGtScanufcB7ECHiPCAY88mT2nvakppByqVQqVvF1e932TSPl6iDbTN6cE6Uk/VHrelrywlxFqXVJAaGVBoSQTUuDKi4C1HVZgXVcBGph%2Bp2GHU0b1Ux8D88NiaIDH4SQQA%3D%3D)).  If the original input was negative, stick a `'-'` in front at the end, when you're done.  So for example, `-10` runs this with `10`, producing 2 ASCII bytes.  Then you store a `'-'` in front, as a third byte of the string.

---

Here's a simple commented NASM version of that, using `div` (slow but shorter code) for 32-bit unsigned integers and a Linux `write` system call.  **It should be easy to port this to 32-bit-mode code** just by changing the registers to `ecx` instead of `rcx`.  But `add rsp,24` will become `add esp, 20` because `push ecx` is only 4 bytes, not 8.  (You should also save/restore `esi` for the usual 32-bit calling conventions, unless you're making this into a macro or internal-use-only function.)

The system-call part is specific to 64-bit Linux.  Replace that with whatever is appropriate for your system, e.g. call the VDSO page for efficient system calls on 32-bit Linux, or use `int 0x80` directly for inefficient system calls.  See [calling conventions for 32 and 64-bit system calls on Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64).  Or see [rkhb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524535/add-2-numbers-and-print-the-result-using-assembly-x86/28524951#28524951) on another question for a 32-bit `int 0x80` version that works the same way.

**If you just need the string without printing it**, `rsi` points to the first digit after leaving the loop.  You can copy it from the tmp buffer to the start of wherever you actually need it.  Or if you generated it into the final destination directly (e.g. pass a pointer arg), you can pad with leading zeros until you reach the front of the space you left for it.  There's no simple way to find out how many digits it's going to be before you start unless you always pad with zeros up to a fixed width.

```
ALIGN 16
; void print_uint32(uint32_t edi)
; x86-64 System V calling convention.  Clobbers RSI, RCX, RDX, RAX.
; optimized for simplicity and compactness, not speed (DIV is slow)
global print_uint32
print_uint32:
    mov    eax, edi              ; function arg

    mov    ecx, 0xa              ; base 10
    push   rcx                   ; ASCII newline '\n' = 0xa = base
    mov    rsi, rsp
    sub    rsp, 16               ; not needed on 64-bit Linux, the red-zone is big enough.  Change the LEA below if you remove this.

;;; rsi is pointing at '\n' on the stack, with 16B of "allocated" space below that.
.toascii_digit:                ; do {
    xor    edx, edx
    div    ecx                   ; edx=remainder = low digit = 0..9.  eax/=10
                                 ;; DIV IS SLOW.  use a multiplicative inverse if performance is relevant.
    add    edx, '0'
    dec    rsi                 ; store digits in MSD-first printing order, working backwards from the end of the string
    mov    [rsi], dl

    test   eax,eax             ; } while(x);
    jnz  .toascii_digit
;;; rsi points to the first digit


    mov    eax, 1               ; __NR_write from /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h
    mov    edi, 1               ; fd = STDOUT_FILENO
    ; pointer already in RSI    ; buf = last digit stored = most significant
    lea    edx, [rsp+16 + 1]    ; yes, it's safe to truncate pointers before subtracting to find length.
    sub    edx, esi             ; RDX = length = end-start, including the \n
    syscall                     ; write(1, string /*RSI*/,  digits + 1)

    add  rsp, 24                ; (in 32-bit: add esp,20) undo the push and the buffer reservation
    ret
```

**Public domain.**  Feel free to copy/paste this into whatever you're working on.  If it breaks, you get to keep both pieces.  (If performance matters, see the links below; you'll want a multiplicative inverse instead of `div`.)

And here's code to call it in a loop counting down to 0 (including 0).  Putting it in the same file is convenient.

```
ALIGN 16
global _start
_start:
    mov    ebx, 100
.repeat:
    lea    edi, [rbx + 0]      ; put +whatever constant you want here.
    call   print_uint32
    dec    ebx
    jge   .repeat


    xor    edi, edi
    mov    eax, 231
    syscall                             ; sys_exit_group(0)
```

Assemble and link with

```
yasm -felf64 -Worphan-labels -gdwarf2 print-integer.asm &&
ld -o print-integer print-integer.o

./print_integer
100
99
...
1
0
```

Use `strace` to see that the only system calls this program makes are `write()` and `exit()`.  (See also the gdb / debugging tips at the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, and the other links there.)

---

##### Related:

- [**32-bit version of this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524535/add-2-numbers-and-print-the-result-using-assembly-x86/28524951#28524951), using `int 0x80` for the `write` system call at the end.  Pretty much the same loop.
- **With `printf`** - [How to print a number in assembly NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194141/how-to-print-a-number-in-assembly-nasm/32853546#32853546) has x86-64 and i386 answers.
- [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309749/nasm-assembly-convert-input-to-integer/49548057#49548057) is the other direction, **string->int**.
- [Printing an integer as a string with AT&T syntax, with Linux system calls instead of printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835456/printing-an-integer-as-a-string-with-att-syntax-with-linux-system-calls-instea/45851398#45851398) - **AT&T version** of the same thing (but for 64-bit integers).  See that for more comments about performance, and a benchmark of `div` vs. compiler-generated code using `mul`.
- [Add 2 numbers and print the result using Assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524535/add-2-numbers-and-print-the-result-using-assembly-x86/28524951#28524951) 32-bit version that's very similar to this.
- This [code-review Q&A](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142842/integer-to-ascii-algorithm-x86-assembly) uses a multiplicative inverse like a compiler would. And it accumulates the string into an 8-byte register instead of into memory, ready store where you want the string to start without extra copying.
- [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-number-to-hex) - power-of-2 bases are special.  Answer includes scalar loop (branchy and table-lookup) and SIMD (SSE2, SSSE3, AVX2, and AVX512 which is amazing for this.)

##### High-performance versions

- Some optimized decimal atoi versions from Daniel Lemire's blog: [without AVX-512](https://lemire.me/blog/2021/11/18/converting-integers-to-fix-digit-representations-quickly/), and much faster [with AVX-512 IFMA](https://lemire.me/blog/2022/03/28/converting-integers-to-decimal-strings-faster-with-avx-512/)
- [With NEON SIMD on Apple M1](https://dougallj.wordpress.com/2022/04/01/converting-integers-to-fixed-width-strings-faster-with-neon-simd-on-the-apple-m1/)
- and some older articles: [How to print integers really fast](https://pvk.ca/Blog/2017/12/22/appnexus-common-framework-its-out-also-how-to-print-integers-faster/) blog post comparing some strategies in C.
  Such as `x % 100` to create more ILP (Instruction Level Parallelism), and either a lookup table or a simpler multiplicative inverse (that only has to work for a limited range, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts/5558614#5558614)) to break up the 0..99 remainder into 2 decimal digits.
  e.g. with `(x * 103) >> 10` using one `imul r,r,imm8` / `shr r,10` as shown in another answer.  Possibly somehow folding that in to the remainder calculation itself.
- https://tia.mat.br/posts/2014/06/23/integer_to_string_conversion.html a similar article.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanna print the value to stdout? If this is the case
you have to use a [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to do so. System calls are OS dependent.

e.g. Linux:
[Linux System Call Table](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html)

The hello world program in this [Tutorial](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/) may give you some insights.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Im working on Windows 7 (x86) at the moment! Have to crack an ALP exam and will have to assemble codes in Win environment in lab! Will have a look at tutorials though! Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so I post reply this way.
@Ira Baxter, perfect answer I just want to add that you don't need to divide 10 times as you posted that you set register cx to value 10. Just divide number in ax until "ax==0"

```
loop1: call dividebyten
       ...
       cmp ax,0
       jnz loop1
```

You also have to store how many digits was there in original number.

```
       mov cx,0
loop1: call dividebyten
       inc cx
```

Anyway you Ira Baxter helped me there is just few ways how to optimize code :)

This is not only about optimization but also formatting. When you want to print number 54 you want print 54 not 0000000054 :)

Answer (score 0):

1 -9 are 1 -9. after that, there must be some conversion that I don't know either. Say you have a 41H in AX (EAX) and you want to print a 65, not 'A' without doing some service call. I think you need to print a character representation of a 6 and a 5 whatever that might be. There must be a constant number that can be added to get there. You need a modulus operator (however you do that in assembly) and loop for all digits.

Not sure, but that's my guess.

Comment: Yeah, that's about right.  In ASCII, the character encodings of `'0'` through `'9'` are contiguous, so you can just calculate `6 + '0'` to get `'6'`.  i.e. use `div` or whatever to get a remainder, then `add edx, '0'` and store that byte to a buffer.  `'0'` = `0x30`, but most assemblers accept character constants, so it's clearer to write your code that way.  (It could be useful to `OR` or `AND` instead of `ADD` / `SUB`, which also works because `0x30` doesn't have any of its low 4 bits set.)