# assembly print the hex number in register

Tags: assembly

I have a code

```
MOV AL, 025H
MOV BL, 034H
MOV BL, 034H
ADD AL,BL
```

but I can't print the hex number in AL register to the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing Hexadecimal Digits with Assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853730/printing-hexadecimal-digits-with-assembly)

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert it to ASCII first if you want to print it on the screen. Thus you have to get the separate hex-digits and convert them to ASCII in order, e.g. 025H -> '0' '2' '5'... You can do so dividing by powers of 16 (10H) and taking the modulo:

```
025H MOD 10H^1 = 5
025H MOD 10H^2 = 2
```

And so on...