# How to print binary number as hex text?

Tags: linux, binary, output, nasm

I write a file asm and print value of FFFFFFFF-1=FFFFFFFE but it print ����. I try use vi command and :%!xxd but it don't exactly, it display 000000: efbf bf0a instead of feff ffff 0a, I too try with value of 0x12345678, surprise is it exactly, it print 0000000: 7756 3412 0a with vi hex editor.
0000000: 7756 3412 0a 
My code:

```
segment .bss
        num2 resb 4
section .text
        global _start
_start: 
        mov dword [num2], 0xFFFFFFFF
        sub [num2], dword 1  
        mov ecx, num2
        mov edx, 4
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        int 0x80  

        mov eax, 1
        int 0x80
```

Value of ���� are binary text?
 Is there a way to make exactly with value of ����?

Comment: To print a hex number you need a to convert the binary (what is in the registers) to `ascii` equivalent. Look at disassembled `itoa` to get a feel for what is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Hexadecimal Digits with Assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853730/printing-hexadecimal-digits-with-assembly)